# Finding a weight function with a specific property

Tags: calculus, examples-counterexamples

I am looking for a (smooth, quickly decaying) function $w : [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $$w(t) \cdot \int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{w(2x)} dx $$ is absolutely integrable on $[0,\infty)$. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If $w>0$, this is impossible, since then $\int_{t/2}^{t}\frac{dx}{w(2x)}>\frac{t}{2w(t)}$.

Comment: $w(t)<w(2x)$ for x in that interval.

Comment: @san I dont get it. Are you assuming that $w$ is monotonically decreasing?

Comment: Yes, that is the assumption.